# ajax.js importing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In **index.html** i imported **ajax.js** with the code :

```
$(function() {
    $('a[name!=modal][name!=skipJQuery]').click(function(){
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        $('#content').scrollTop();

            return false;
}); });
```

*#content* is a **div** that load pages. The pages inside *#content* are not recognizing **ajax.js** imported on top of **index.html**. How can i fix this? ..to make the pages loaded inside *#content* recognize the **ajax.js**?

Comment: Did you load jQuery as well?

Comment: What is happening due to that ?

Comment: In index.html? Yes.
If i import ajax.js again inside tha page on div#content this works correctly, but i had to import ajax.js inside all the pages and this isn't good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the click event not firing on links in the imported content? If so, maybe try using the 'on' event binder.

```
$("body").on("click", "a[name!=modal][name!=skipJQuery]", function(){
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    $('#content').scrollTop();
    return false;
});
```